# Como fazer um botão de voltar ao menu inicial? Uso html e css

Tags: html, css

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>JdBEdit - Demo</title>
    <meta content="IE=edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible"/>
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport"/>
</head>
<body id="bg">
    <div id="elem1">
        <button class="start href"> START </button>

        <a href="https://m.youtube.com/user/jadson8255">
            <button id="b1">

20 Buscar
            </button>
        </a>

        <a href="https://m.youtube.com/channel/UCLRW29kscCnup6lYpLp-mDw">
            <button id="b2">
            MALUCO BR2
            </button>
        </a>

        <a href="https://m.youtube.com/channel/UChjOkhXUsQExsAG5hffIuJw">
            <button id="b3">
            MALUCO BR3
            </button>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div id="elem2" style="display: none;">
        <button id="bcen">10000</button>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Não deu para entender direito o que vc quer. Daria para vc dar mais detalhes?

Comment: Seja mais especifico com sua pergunta, dê mais detalhes, poste o código completo, incluindo o css. [como perguntar?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

**Usei um link com background e padding para criar um botão de inicio e coloquei `/` pra indicar a url do inicio**

```css
.inicio {
    padding: 15px;
    background-color:#232323;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

```html
<a class="inicio" href="/">INICIO</a>
```

**Você também pode adicionar o css diretamente no elemento, adicionando `style=""`, assim:**

```
<a style="padding:15px;background-color:#232323;color:#fff;text-decoration:none;" class="inicio" href="/">INICIO</a>
```

Comment: Blz vou testar aqui!

Comment: Então eu consigo ai no meio das aspas eu coloco a id do menu?

Comment: Sua duvida é de como fazer um botão de inicio, eu respondi.